# Paramterized SQL Query with RODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, odbc

I have the following SQL query which I submit via `RODBC` to SQL Server

```
test = "SELECT ticker, date, PX_LAST FROM dbo.bb_si_ts_data_lc
            WHERE ticker = 'SPX Index' AND date > '2014-12-31'"
ts_db_monthly = sqlQuery(conn_db,test)
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now I tried to parameterize the query

```
date_input_start = paste("2014-12-31")
date_sql_start = paste("AND date>= (\"",date_input_start,"\")")
ticker_input = 'SPX Index'
ticker_sql_input = paste("WHERE ticker IN(\"",ticker_input,"\")")
fields_input = c("ticker","date","PX_LAST")
db = "dbo.bb_si_ts_data_lc"
query_test = paste("SELECT ticker,date,PX_LAST FROM",db,ticker_sql_input,date_sql_start)
ts_db_monthly_test = sqlQuery(conn_db,query_test)
```

This, however, does not work. The error message I get is:

```
[1] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name ' SPX Index '."                                                                 
[2] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name ' 2014-12-31 '."                                                                
[3] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT ticker,date,PX_LAST FROM dbo.bb_si_ts_data_lc WHERE ticker IN(\" SPX Index \") AND date>= (\" 2014-12-31 \")'"
```

Can you help me to get this code correct? It appears to me that the problem circles around the quotation marks.

Comment: Why not just `date_sql_start = paste0("AND date>= '",date_input_start, "'")` and `ticker_sql_input = paste0("WHERE ticker IN '",ticker_input,"'")`?

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes, not double quotes.

But you should use question marks to indicate your parameters and pass in the parameters separately. Try this article to help: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html

Comment: Right, but be wary of sql injection vulnerabilities. Using parameters is definitely preferred.